# Windows. Удаление директории которая занята другим процессом

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Например есть директория

```
C:\Users\Desktop\test
```

В директории test находится программа app.exe, при запуске которой выполняется команда

```
choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 1 & rmdir /q /s C:\Users\Desktop\test
```

Можно ли как-нибудь удалить директорию test в таком случае?

Сейчас при выполнении программы, удаляется только все содержимое test, а test не удаялется т.к занята процессом приложением app.exe

Comment: И сам `app.exe` удаляется?

Comment: Да, все содержимое.

Comment: Там команда поинтереснее. С задержкой как я понял. Поправил тело темы.

Comment: Пока `app.exe` будет запущен - директория и программа будет залочена, соответственно удалить не сможете.